# OpenGL GLSL, stuck viewing pyramid from "behind"

Tags: macos, cocoa, opengl, graphics, glsl

It appears that my pyramid is smaller in the front and bigger in the back.

```
-(void)drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect
{
    // get the dimensions of the window
    NSSize dim = [self frame].size;

    // clear the background with color
    glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.4);
    glViewport(0, 0, dim.width, dim.height);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    // cube position data
    GLfloat vertices[] = {0.0, 100.0, 0.0, -50.0, 0.0, 50.0, 50.0, 0.0, 50.0, 50.0, 0.0, -50.0, -50.0, 0.0, -50.0};

    // cube indices data
    GLubyte indices[] = {0, 1, 2, 0, 2, 3, 0, 3, 4, 0, 4, 1, 1, 4, 3, 1, 3, 2};

    // cube color data
    GLfloat color[] = {0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0,
    0.0, 0.3, 0.8, 1.0, 
    1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 
    0.5, 0.0, 0.8, 1.0, 
    0.5, 0.6, 0.3, 1.0};

    // bind each array of data to separate buffers
    // bind cube position data to the first buffer
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexBuffers[0]);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
    // bind the cube color data to the second buffer
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexBuffers[1]);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(color), color, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

    // enable the shader program
    GLuint programID = [self loadShaders];
    glUseProgram(programID);

    // enable vertex attributes
    // enable cube position attributes
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexBuffers[0]);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(VERTEX_POS_INDEX);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
    // enable cube color attributes
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexBuffers[1]);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(VERTEX_COLOR_INDEX);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

    // point to the enabled attribute data
    glVertexAttribPointer(VERTEX_POS_INDEX, VERTEX_POS_SIZE, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, vertices);
    glVertexAttribPointer(VERTEX_COLOR_INDEX, VERTEX_COLOR_SIZE, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, color);

    GLfloat offset[] = {0.0, 0.0, -200.0};
    GLint offsetUnif = glGetUniformLocation(programID, "offset");
    GLint zNearUnif = glGetUniformLocation(programID, "zNear");
    GLint zFarUnif = glGetUniformLocation(programID, "zFar");
    GLint frustumScaleUnif = glGetUniformLocation(programID, "frustumScale");

    glUniform3fv(offsetUnif, 1, offset);
    glUniform1f(frustumScaleUnif, 1.0f);
    glUniform1f(zNearUnif, 0.1);
    glUniform1f(zFarUnif, 1000.0);

    // draw the elements
    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, sizeof(indices)/sizeof(GLubyte), GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, indices);

    glDisableVertexAttribArray(VERTEX_POS_INDEX);
    glDisableVertexAttribArray(VERTEX_COLOR_INDEX);
    glUseProgram(0);

    // flush buffer
    glFlush();
    [[self openGLContext] flushBuffer];

}
```

Here is the vertex shader:

```
#version 120

attribute vec3 position;
attribute vec4 inColor;

uniform vec3 offset;
uniform float zNear;
uniform float zFar;
uniform float frustumScale;

varying vec4 outColor;

void main()
{
    vec4 cameraPos = vec4(position.x, position.y, -position.z, 1.0) + vec4(offset.x, offset.y, offset.z, 0.0);
    vec4 clipPos;

    clipPos.xy = cameraPos.xy * frustumScale;

    clipPos.z = cameraPos.z * (zNear + zFar) / (zNear - zFar);
    clipPos.z += 2 * zNear * zFar / (zNear - zFar);

    clipPos.w = -cameraPos.z;

    gl_Position = clipPos;
    outColor = inColor;
}
```

When I run the code I get this image, note it looks as though the pyramid with bigger in the back than the front:

[image: Pyramid]

I circled the "front" corners (though I should be seeing this from the other side thus they are actually the rear corners). Any thoughts or suggests as to where the problem may lie?

Comment: OK, the picture is correct, it shows the true front (after checking the vertices against the assigned colors). Mystery is still around the back looking bigger than the front...

Answer (score 1):

It seems, that you don't apply a perspective projection matrix within your shader, thus the lack of view angle/depth, causing sort of an orthogonal projection.

The matrices you'd want to apply within the shader are `gl_ModelViewMatrix` (object & camera transform), `gl_ProjectionMatrix` (projection) or `gl_ModelViewProjectionMatrix` (object & camera transform & projection). As these builtin uniforms are deprecated, you need to pass them yourselves.

Comment: can those matrices be constructed in the vertex shader itself?

Comment: Although it is possible to initialize matrices within a shader, they vary per object, camera position and view angle, thus it is recommended to calculate them in C and pass them using `glUniformMatrix4fv()`.

Comment: I am doing the Projection math, just not in matrix form. I based mine off this: http://arcsynthesis.org/gltut/Positioning/Tut04%20Perspective%20Projection.html, Example 4.2

Comment: I see, try to adjust `frustumScale` to a value other than `1.0f`. Still, you don't seem to be able to 'turn the camera'. To go with this approach, you might want to add some sort of rotation, which is usually contained in `gl_ModelViewMatrix`.

Comment: I adjusted the frustumScale, only made the pyramid smaller, but the back still appeared "buffer" than the front. I will try your idea of computing the M, V, and P matrices in C and passing them to the vertex shader. I have been on this problem for 5 weeks now...

Comment: You may also check the polygon winding and the culling mode

Comment: I have glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE), glCullFace(GL_BACK), glFrontFace(GL_CCW).